# Edit the host link for a web service in tomcat

Tags: android, jsp, servlets, google-cloud-messaging, unknown-host

I am quite new to programming with JSPs, servlets and also android programming.
I am getting `unknownhostexception` when i post from my jsp file. I came to know that the host I am using is not correct. My specific error is `java.net.UnknownHostException:android.googleapis.com` whereas it should be `android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`
Please help me change the host name!!!

Comment: i got got the ans go to contant.java